# Why would this method return Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method that uses the .NET membership provider to retrieve some data for each user using the profile provider. However I get a error in my application's log that states

> in method `GetUsers():` Index was outside the bounds of the array.

The "in method `GetUsers()`" is added by my logging mechanism. The rest is strictly .NET.

```
protected Dictionary<string, string> Getusers()
{
    try
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> userDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        //Get string array of users in role from RoleProvider
        var users = Roles.GetUsersInRole("MyRoleName");

        //loop through the array of usernames
        foreach (string user in users)
        {
            //Get user's first name and last name from the profile provider
            ProfileCommon profile = (ProfileCommon)ProfileCommon.Create(user);

            //add new key value pair with user name as the key and lastname,firstname as value
            userDictionary.Add(user, string.Concat(profile.LastName + ",", profile.FirstName));
        }

        //sort the dictionary by the value not the key
        //a little linq to do the sorting
        var sortedDict = (from entry in userDictionary orderby entry.Value ascending select entry).ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);

        return sortedDict;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogController.LogError( "In Method -- Getusers() --" + ex.Message);
        //if error occurs return empty dictionary
        return new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line exactly throws that exception?

Comment: You're tossing your call stack, which could tell you where the error's actually being generated. Change ex.Message to ex.ToString() and take a look.

Comment: Looking on the code you have to actually LOG the exception, the exception itself could possibly be raised even in `Roles.GetUsersInRole` or in `ProfileCommon.CreateUser`, i.e. in one of methods the `GetUsers` method calls. I would add a stack trace logging so that you can catch the actual line in your code that has the error.

Comment: As a side note, you need to question why you're sorting the dictionary that you return. Dictionaries are not sorted, so this isn't achieving anything.

Comment: I will get back to you on this. It's not occuring in our development and test envrionments but in our prod environment. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you have values in the userDictionary ?

I wonder if this is the line of code that you see the exception

```
var sortedDict = (from entry in userDictionary orderby entry.Value ascending select entry).ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

if you post the stack trace it will be easier to know.